# How to change the CSS from the last child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've got the following code (http://jsfiddle.net/Jeroen94/9D6Z6/):

```
<div class="inbox">‌
    <div class="something 1">
        <a class="inbox-message">Message 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="something 2">
        <a class="inbox-message">Message 2</a>
    </div>
</div>

.inbox-message {
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.inbox a:last-child {  /* This doesn't work... */
    border: 0;
}
```

I'd like to remove the border from the last message (in this case the second one), but I don't succeed in doing it, because I don't really understand how to work with `last-child`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the rule to:

```
.inbox :last-child a{
    border: 0;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9D6Z6/2/)

You could also have done `.inbox div:last-child a{`, but it's not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the inbox-message class onto the code.

```
<div class="inbox">‌
    <div class="something 1">
        <a class="inbox-message">Message 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="something 2">
        <a class="inbox-message">Message 2</a>
    </div>
</div>

.inbox-message {
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.inbox .inbox-message a:last-child {  /* This doesn't work... */ border: 0;}
```